# Xamarin.mac WKWebView leaves 2 orphaned processes

Tags: xamarin, wkwebview, xamarin.mac

My app is a document-based Xamarin.mac app that uses WKWebView to display HTML content generated in-code.  Each time a new window is created, 2 new processes are also created: 'APP_NAME Networking' and 'about:'.  However, when the window is closed, the two processes remain.  Open 10 windows, close 10 windows, and I have 20 orphaned processes.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to make these go away when the window is closed?

(EDIT)
Please note that these are not orphaned objects/data structures, but independently running system processes that are owned by the app, but not by the document window/view controller that spawned them.  Quit the app, the child processes die.  But close the window, and the child processes live on...

Comment: You can something maintaining a native ref. Make sure you release all of the native objects that return an `IDisposable` Using the Xamarin Profiler will help track those down.

Comment: @SushiHangover I think all native objects are IDisposable in Xamarin.

Comment: I built a test app that's just a new document-based app, a WKWebView in the document space, and an outlet called 'webView'.  Build and run, and the extra processes are spawned in the Activity Monitor each time a window is opened, but never go away.

Comment: Here's a link to the project: [https://dropbox.com/s/nk0t6oznklvf6u2/OrphanedProcessTest.zip?dl=0](Test App Source)

Comment: @IvanIčin Yes?....

Answer (score 1):

Memory management in .NET is based on the garbage collection. As such it is indeterminate from the point of app or developer. Meaning that things like above are not unexpected in .NET.

In Xamarin there is the additional problem - Xamarin is keeping reference on native resources, but it has no idea what those resources are and how much computer resources they take, so the automatic garbage collection is frequently not happening when you expect it.

It is suggested that you should `Dispose` the important native resources that you don't need. I would definitely consider WKWebView among such resources.

Other than that you may also initiate garbage collection manually, but that is not recommended unless really needed.

Comment: Dispose is auto-added to the ViewController.designer.cs file when the outlet is created in Xcode.  I added GC.Collect() to both the ViewDidDisappear method and a destructor method.  No impact.  Note that these are not orphaned objects or memory, per se... not even threads.  These are actual system processes that are being orphaned.

Comment: @DesignDB Dispose is not auto added in the sense that it never gets executed. And it is not called Dispose but something like release designer outlets as far as I remember. But in either case it will never be called unless you do it.

Comment: Got it. It was auto-built, but it never occurred to me that it wouldn't also be auto-called.  It appears calling that function is *not* killing the child processes, regardless of if it is called in ViewWillDisappear, ViewDidDisappear, or the class destructor.  Is there a "perfect" place to call it?

Comment: @DesignDB I can't check anything more right now, but if what you say is true (process is not killed) the best thing for you to do is to build a XCode project and see if the problem appears. If it doesn't then submit it as a bug to Xamarin, if it appears in XCode too then it might be Apple's bug or it might be a thing you shouldn't care about.